# tableselect make specific checkbox checked

Tags: php, forms, symfony, drupal, drupal-8

```
foreach ($courses as $user) {
    $options[$user['uid']] = [
        'coursecode'  => $user['coursecode'],
        'coursename'  => $user['coursename'],
        'credithours' => $user['credithours'],
        'coursetype'  => $user['coursetype'],
        'building'    => $user['building'],
        'place'       => $user['place'],
        'day'         => $user['day'],
        'time'        => $user['time'],
    ];
}
$form['table'] = [
    '#type'       => 'tableselect',
    '#header'     => $header,
    '#options'    => $options,
    '#empty'      => t('No Courses found'),
    '#js_select'  => false,
    '#attributes' => ['checked' => 'checked'],
];
```

this code generates all courses I can register is there any way to check specific values as default, I had a problem with making a specific checkbox checked

so anyhelp ?
I'm using drupal 8

Answer (score 0):

//Inside your foreach loop

```
foreach($courses as $user) {
  $default_value[$user['uid']] = 1; // use 1 or 0 as appropriate

}
```

// now with your table select

```
$form['table']['#default_value'] = $default_value;
```

// default_value is not provided with each options, rather an array of default values is provided in the tableselect main array.

Hope this solves your problem.